# how to show the specific rows to the specific users in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet and want to show only specific rows to the user and remaining data to be hidden and the same processes should be done with another user.
Example: I want to show 1-5 rows to the 1st user,6-10 rows to the 2nd user and 1-10 rows to the 3rd user.

Comment: Possiblu use `AutoFilter`? And as per user, check their username upon `Workbook_open` event. Other than that, there is not much to go by in your question.

Comment: How do you plan to track which users see which rows?